# RestSharp + Xamarin - "Request failed with status code InternalServerError"

Tags: c#, xamarin, restsharp

This code until recently worked normally. Now it always gives the error "Request failed with status code InternalServerError".

I tested it in Postman, and everything works as expected. The problem is only in my application.

Does anyone have any idea why it might have stopped working?

RestSharp Version 107.3.0

```
var restClient = new RestClient($"{urlAcesso}?method={methodname}");
var request = new RestRequest();

request.AddOrUpdateHeader("accessKey", accessKey);

request.AddParameter("usuario", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.usuario), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("dispositivoId", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.dispositivoId), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("session", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.session), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("id", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.id.ToString()), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("idApp", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.idApp.ToString()), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("qtdImagens", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.qtdeImagens.ToString()), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(image1)) request.AddFile("fileImagem_1", await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(image1), Path.GetFileName(image1));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(image2)) request.AddFile("fileImagem_2", await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(image2), Path.GetFileName(image2));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(image3)) request.AddFile("fileImagem_3", await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(image3), Path.GetFileName(image3));

var response = await restClient.PostAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is the OLD code that still works until version 106.15.0 but that is incompatible with 107.3.0.

```
var restClient = new RestClient($"{urlAcesso}?method={methodname}");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("accessKey", accessKey);

request.AddParameter("usuario", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.usuario), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("dispositivoId", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.dispositivoId), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("session", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.session), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("id", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.id.ToString()), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("idApp", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.idApp.ToString()), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

request.AddParameter("qtdImagens", EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt(jsonparameters.qtdeImagens.ToString()), ParameterType.GetOrPost);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(image1)) request.AddFileBytes("fileImagem_1", await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(image1), Path.GetFileName(image1));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(image2)) request.AddFileBytes("fileImagem_2", await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(image2), Path.GetFileName(image2));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(image3)) request.AddFileBytes("fileImagem_3", await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(image3), Path.GetFileName(image3));

var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The only differences are :
Changed from

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

to

```
var request = new RestRequest();
response = await restClient.PostAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: an "internal server error" means there is something going wrong with your server code.  Debug it or look at the server logs

Comment: request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data"); seems to be not working as expected anymore.

Comment: https://restsharp.dev/v107/#headers

Comment: I still couldn't make it work. I updated the original post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this structure?

```
    var сlient = new RestClient(url);
    var restRequest = new RestRequest(method);

    ... your params

    restRequest.AddStringBody(inputJson, ContentType.Json);
    var result = client.PostAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This worked for me.
Maybe this article about updates https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107 will help you